# JS assets in a subdomain wont load on ff & ie but chrome is all good

Tags: javascript, css, ssl, cloudflare

We are building a Saas product and have purchased a bootstrap dashboard, all the JS/CSS assets are loaded though a sobdomain via our CDN.

Works perfectly on chrome but on ie and ff the components do not load properly, on ff I get the following errors:
TypeError: can't access dead object
ReferenceError: event is not defined

A link to a non working example is below (We don't want to give access to our working dashboard for commercial reasons) You can see the error when click on the "dropdown" menu item. As far as I can tell, all the assets are loading correctly.

http://hunchbuzz.com/acme/index.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, take your bugs one by one. Did you turn on the JavaScript Debugger when you tested your page in IE? In the F12 developer tools, select Script and then Start Debugging.

First there were a couple of errors in `jquery.sparkline.min.js` which I ignored for the moment. Then I tried clicking your 'dropdown' link and got this error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault' 
custom.js, line 3 character 1193
```

The highlighted code is (reformatted for readability):

```
$('.dropmenu').click( function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Do you see the problem? What is `event`? The code should be:

```
$('.dropmenu').click( function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

The fact that it worked in any browser at all is probably due to the global `event` variable that some browsers create for compatibility with very old code.

Now back to the sparkline problems. I see it hitting two errors in `jquery.sparkline.min.js`, but with the minimized code the problem isn't jumping out at me the way the other one did.

When you're debugging, it would help a lot to load the non-minified versions of `jquery.sparkline.js`, `custom.js`, jQuery, etc. Then you'll have readable code to look at in the debugger, which should make it easier to spot these problems.

Comment: Thanks, ill have a look at this and un-minify the source code. Whats confusing me is that it works perfectly when I have the assets in a sub folder rather than a sub domain.